# LibGDX ClickListener does not recieve input

Tags: java, android, libgdx

So far, I have been able to add ClickListeners to all of my buttons without any problem. This malfunction occurred when I tried to add the listener to an actor through a Runnable Action.

```
    RunnableAction addListener = Actions.run(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tapCounter = 0;
            egg.addListener(new ClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                    tapCounter++;
                    if (tapCounter > 3 && tapCounter < 7)
                        egg.setDrawable(new TextureRegionDrawable(eggAtlas.findRegion("egg.1")));
                    else if (tapCounter > 6 && tapCounter < 10)
                        egg.setDrawable(new TextureRegionDrawable(eggAtlas.findRegion("egg.2")));
                    else if (tapCounter > 9 && tapCounter < 13)
                        egg.setDrawable(new TextureRegionDrawable(eggAtlas.findRegion("egg.3")));
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

The code above is supposed to change the texture of the actor "egg" when tapped a certain amount of times. The problem is that nothing is happening! Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you use input multiplexer or input processor ? You probably did not define your input processor.

Comment: How you're adding this action? add some more piece of code

Comment: Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage or your input processor);

Comment: It must be the input processor. Thank you!